# R: source_gist not working

Tags: r, devtools

I am trying to use `source_gist` from the `devtools` package but I am encountering an error:

```
> library(devtools)
> source_gist("524eade46135f6348140")
Error in r_files[[which]] : invalid subscript type 'closure'
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Traced it to `devtools:::find_gist`.  Haven't figured out the problem though.  It looks like the local variable `which` is not being recognized.  Same error as if you did `1[[which]]` in the global environment, since `which()` is a base function. Weird.

Comment: In `devtools:::find_gist`, there is no `if()` condition for if `length(r_files) == 1`, which it does in your case.  I ran the first two lines of `find_gist` in the console to get `r_files`.  That looks like a bug to me.  I would take this to the [devtools github page](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) and file an issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Agree this is a bug, which I see you've [submitted](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/1266).

A temporary workaround is to specify the `filename` option:

```
devtools::source_gist("524eade46135f6348140", filename = "ggplot_smooth_func.R")
```

Comment: This has been [fixed as of 2017/08/01](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/commit/c0121bff3e70f2891eaacf94ff14acfb4eaab37e), although you'll need the [development version](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) until this fix is pushed to CRAN.